# Can I have formulas in the body of an R Markdown HTML flextable

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I would like to include formulas, with greek letters and subscripts, in the body of a flextable in an R Markdown HTML document.  My code below is as close as I can get.

````
---
title: "html"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
```


```{r make-table}
epi <- data.frame(label= c("Exposured", "Not Exposed"), 
                  Yes = c("π_11", "π_21"),
                  No = c("π_12", "π_22"))

theHeader <- data.frame(
  col_keys = colnames(`epi`),
  line1 = c("", rep("Has Outcome", 2)),
  line2 = c("", "Yes", "No")
)

flextable(epi, col_keys = theHeader$col_keys) %>%
  set_header_df(
    mapping = theHeader,
    key = "col_keys"
  ) %>% 
  theme_booktabs() %>% 
  autofit(part = "all") %>%    
  align(align = "center", part = "all") %>% 
  merge_h(part = "header") %>% 
  align_nottext_col(align = "center")
```
````

It produces this:

[image]

Is there a sane way to print formulas in the body of a flextable?

I am writing lecture notes. So references (suggested readings) to support a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: support for formula is existing but limited https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/display.html#sugar-functions-for-complex-formatting-1. no mathjax support for example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I found your examples for formatting titles/labels but I am trying to include the formulas as the cells of a table.  Is there an example floating around that shows how to embed formulas in the table body?

Comment: yes, use part="body". I don't have other resource to provide than https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable.